# Floating point exception in NASM

Tags: exception, assembly, nasm

I am writing a little divisibility program in nasm for learning purposes but I keep getting the "floating point exception" whenever I try running it.  Here is the code:

```
segment .data
x dw 7
y dw 2

segment .bss
num resb 2
segment .text
global _start
_start:
mov cx, 1
mov bx, 0

label1:
mov ax, cx
xor bx, bx
xor edx, edx
mov bx, word [x]
div bx
cmp edx, 0
jne next
mov ax, cx
xor bx, bx
xor edx, edx
mov bx, word [y]
div dx
cmp edx, 0
jne next

mov [num], cx

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, num
mov edx, 2
int 80h

add bx, 1
next:
add cx, 1
cmp cx, 100
jle label1

exit:   
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 80h
```

I would appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this line in your code:

```
div dx
```

Obviously dividing by `dx` is a bad idea since `dx` also is part of the dividend, and you've correctly set `dx` to zero prior to the division. I assume that this is a typo and that you really meant to write

```
div bx
```

Comment: Indeed, this was a typo.  Thank you for pointing it out;  I do however notice a different problem, namely nothing is getting output to the screen. Any idea why that is?

Comment: The `sys_write` syscall doesn't do conversion of integers to strings before output. If you want to print an integer you'll have to convert it to a string first.